# Post request giving CORS error in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I am getting CORS error on localhost during post request call. below is the code

```
 fetch('http://sandbox.mywebsite.com/api//product-list/', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    "category_id":1
  })
})
```

Same giving proper response when testing on https://inspector.swagger.io/builder .
Any help will be appreciated [image]

Comment: Always try searching for the error message first. There's most likely an existing answer. Or dozens.

Comment: yes, thank you. actually, I saw that post and tried all the methods but still getting errors.

Comment: The header needs to be set on the *server*. If you could simply use `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',` in your fetch call to circumvent it, the whole thing became pretty pointless.

Comment: thank you for the update. I already used this in my code during API call

Comment: ? Again: you cannot do this from the client. If you want to fetch something from an API without CORS, you need to route the request through your own server.